# In Brazil, is the suspension of the president optional while the impeachment trial takes place?

Tags: impeachment, brazil

In Brazil, in 2016, their president was suspended while being tried by the Senate, which also removed her from office in the end. The suspension vote [took place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Dilma_Rousseff#Senate_vote_on_suspension) in the Senate as well.

Was this suspension optional from a law/procedure standpoint? I.e. could the actual trial in the Senate have proceeded without suspending the president first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Chamber of Deputies votes to impeach the President, then the President is suspended as per Article 86 of the [Constitution](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Brazil_2014.pdf):

> If two-thirds of the Chamber of Deputies accept an accusation against the President
>   of the Republic, he shall be tried before the Supreme Federal Tribunal for common
>   criminal offenses or before the Federal Senate for impeachable offenses.
>
> §1°. The President shall be suspended from his duties:
>
> > I. in common criminal offenses, if the accusation or criminal complaint is
> >     received by the Supreme Federal Tribunal;
> >
> > II. in impeachable offenses, after proceedings are instituted by the Federal
> >     Senate.
>
> §2°. If, after a period of one hundred eighty days, the trial has not been concluded,
>   the President's suspension shall end, without prejudice to normal progress of
>   the proceedings.